# Alternative Approach For generating list<key> from dict<string,string> where dict.value = "someValue"

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm trying to generate a list of keys (type `string`) i.e `List<string>` from `Dictionary<string,string>` where the value in dictionary object is `"someValue"`:

```
Dictionary<string,string> DictionaryObject = someMethodReturningDict();
List<string> listOfKeys = DictionaryObject.Where(s => s.Value == 
                          "someValue").ToList().Select(a => a.Key).ToList();
```

I think there should be a better approach.

Comment: Drop the intermediate ToList. Rest everything seems fine.

Comment: Thankyou @bashrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think below is best way for your situation:**

```
Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryObject = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var result = DictionaryObject.Where(p => p.Value == "aaaa").Select(p => p.Key).ToList();
```